# UITextField Tap Detection

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have been having issues regarding having a tap event on my textfield. I have tried almost everything. Almost. From including the textfield delegate to calling it, to making the textfield into an action, all the way to adding UIGestureRecognizers and using the made selector in a function form.

my textfield is also in another swift file as it is inside a custom cell. I would very much appreciate if anyone could help me on this issue. I have been searching for a while now.

There isn't really any reason to show code since all that I'd like is to have some code execute once the user is inside the textview and typing. I know that the UITextViewDelegate handles this wonderfully, but it isn't working for me. The code is being done inside the custom cell file. I'm doing something incorrect I believe. I have added the

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    }
```

but I have no idea on how to connect my textview to that function.
Also, when I use the

```
var text_view_tap_gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapped:"))
    textfield.addGestureRecognizer(text_view_tap_gesture)
```

it doesn't register anything whatsoever.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You say there's no reason to show code, but that's exactly how this problem can be diagnosed. For example, why isn't UITextViewDelegate handling it wonderfully, as you said it does? Surely there's an explainable reason. It's just hard to say without knowing if you've even defined the `tapped` function. Where did you put that textFieldDelegate function?

Comment: Sorry for that. It's just that I thought it would be a simple fix. I just thought code wan't needed since I wanted people to assume it was very basic. A normal textfieldview. Also. I have defined the tapped function. I implied it in the beginning of using the made selector into a function. Aka, defining. Sorry for not being clear. I'm still fairly new with stack overflow despite having an account for a while. i just don't use it as much. I appreciate your feedback as well. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, just not sure where to start here. You indicated some interactions between your code, but we can't see them. There could be a bunch of reasons. Are you getting any error messages? That would be a great place to start

Comment: No. No errors. The only thing I have is a risk but that is due to the constraints which I'm not worried about at the moment.  I just have a simple  @IBOutlet var textfield: UITextField! in a custom cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can add a target for the "EditingDidBegin" control event.

```
 self.textField.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:" forControlEvents: .EditingDidBegin)
```